# ActiveMerchant/Spree - Is there a per-transaction/per-account commission to the creators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins, activemerchant, spree

This is probably a silly question but if you use ActiveMerchant (or spree), do the creators of ActiveMerchant (or spree) take a commission? Since it's open source I wouldn't expect them to. But at the same time, because it's such a large undertaking to create a processing gateway, it would not surprise me if they wanted some compensation for their efforts. Or is it simply the case that you only pay a commission to the credit card companies on any payments you receive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They don't take a commission.

Answer (score 2):

Shopify charges a commission but Shopify is a paid service.  They have donated the gateway piece of the code under the ActiveMerchant project.  Spree is a complete open source project (New BSD License) and so there is no charge for use of that software.  Spree is a software project, however, not a service.

Normal gateway charges obviously still apply.